Error: Could not resolve dependencies for com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.9.0 after updating Java, Gradle, and Flutter
I'm working on an Flutter project, and I recently updated Java, Gradle, and Flutter to the latest versions. After the update, I started getting the following errors when trying to build my project:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.9.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.9.0/gradle-8.9.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.9.0/gradle-8.9.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:latest_version.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/latest_version/groovy-all-latest_version.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/latest_version/groovy-all-latest_version.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Here are the details of my project configuration:
android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.9.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.chat'
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.chat"
        minSdkVersion 23 
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22'
        }
    }
}

wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Environment details:

Java version: 22.0.2 (build 22.0.2+9-70)
Gradle version: 8.9
Flutter version: Latest

I've checked the Maven repositories, but I still get the "Could not resolve" errors for com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.9.0 and org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:latest_version.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

I have the same problem. And the odd thing is gradle 8.9 is in my projects .gradle directory, but gradlew seems not to use it. (my version is com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.9 (no trailing .0))


Gradle itself and Android Gradle Plugin (com.android.tools.build:gradle) does not have same version, since they are different products, each with it own release cycle.

That said,8.9.0 is not valid version of com.android.tools.build:gradle.  Latest version now is 8.5.1 and you should use it. Also, you can check latest release here

latest_release is not correct for using latest version of some dependency. latest.release should be used. But in any case, this is not preferred way of resolving versions – it's better to use specific versions. Here is docs on that matter

